# Using AC solenoids with rectified DC

Tags: ac, opto-isolator, triac

If one wanted to avoid triac opto-couplers for AC solenoids, would it be OK to rectify the AC, without filter capacitance or regulation, then drive from a transistor opto-coupler?

I would think the solenoid would not know the difference.

There would only be a positive half-cycle rather than a negative and positive alternating.

Comment: Welcome! Please draw a schematic. Add a link to the solenoid in question.

Comment: It's unclear why you ask this, because with those components, it's already possible to drive AC solenoid with AC and have pulsed DC through the transistor optocoupler.

Comment: It's not so much about schematic or wiring .. but more about complex impedance .. in other words what is the difference between full cycle AC connected to an AC solenoid vs rectified AC which becomes DC. What problems might there be?

Comment: Before you go into any discussions, though, please can you edit your question and add a schematic, as asked for some time back. Otherwise, people can't be sure exactly what they're talking about to you. Thanks very much. (Incidentally, '...' isn't punctuation for normal sentences, easier to read without it.)

Comment: You must realize that the current in an AC solenoid is limited by inductance. With DC, the coil saturates and current is limited by DC resistance. Typically a 120 VAC solenoid might take 20-30 VDC for the same current.

Comment: Yes the current in an AC solenoid is limited by inductance ,, but that is with filtered regulated DC. what about just positive half cycles? .. I am wondering if the iron would be magnetized since there is no alternation ?

Answer (score 4):

There is no need for driving AC solenoids with DC even if you have DC switching circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faM81o.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: This is close to what I am saying ... remove the opto and feed the AC into the bridge and then the DC direct to the solenoid. I should have never mentioned the opto since it is misleading.

Answer (score 2):

> If one wanted to avoid triac opto-couplers for AC solenoids, would it be OK to rectify the AC, without filter capacitance or regulation, then drive from a transistor opto-coupler?

No. AC solenoids regulate the current by inductance (which changes during operation) and by resistance so using a DC supply would lead to excess current.

use a relay, solid-state-relay, or opto-triac to control the solenoids.

Comment: You might be able to use DC for an AC solenoid, but the voltage will be around 20% of the AC rating to get the same current. Also, the inductance will usually increase by a factor of around 3 as the armature enters the solenoid, or the relay clapper closes the magnetic circuit and closes the air gap. So the DC current may need to be reduced so that there will be less power wasted as heat.